# Oracle Trigger Creation Issue

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

i am working on an assignment which does the below.

> create a PL/SQL trigger called STAFF_TRIGGER on the STAFF table. This
>   trigger will be executed after every insert or update.  a.For inserts,
>   this trigger should put the new STAFF.STAFF_ID value, the user in
>   MOD_USER, and the system date in MOD_TIMESTAMP to record the creation
>   of the data into STAFF_LOG.  b.For updates, this trigger should put
>   the previous STAFF values into the corresponding STAFF_LOG column as
>   well as recording the MOD_USER and MOD_TIMESTAMP.

So far this is what i have, i am using oracle database express edition.

```
create trigger staff_trigger
after insert or update on staff
for each row 

begin 

if inserting then 
   insert into staff_log (staff_id, mod_user, mod_timestamp)
   values(new.employee_id, new.last_name, sysdate);
end if;

if updating then  
   insert into staff_log (mod_user, mod_timestamp)
   values(new.last_name, sysdate);
end if;

end;
```

When i execute the code i am getting the below error.

```
ERROR at line 9: PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored7. if inserting then 
8.    insert into staff_log (staff_id, mod_user, mod_timestamp)
9.    values(new.employee_id, new.last_name, sysdate);
10. end if;
```

Any ideas as to what may be the cause of this?

Comment: Tip: when you're putting code in your post, select the code and click the button that looks like `{ }`.  This will format the code and make it easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

try this (`:new` instead of `new`)

```
create trigger staff_trigger
after insert or update on staff
for each row 

begin 

if inserting then 
   insert into staff_log (staff_id, mod_user, mod_timestamp)
   values(:new.employee_id, :new.last_name, sysdate);
end if;

if updating then  
   insert into staff_log (mod_user, mod_timestamp)
   values(:new.last_name, sysdate);
end if;

end;
```